# How to add delay on animation by calculating `index` value in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have 2 elements in a group and I am selecting `groups` using `selectAll` method. But I want to add some delay on it's child elements on `transition`. What is the correct approach for this?

My try is not working at all:

```
var fadeHandler = function () {
    d3.selectAll('.subAppGroup') //parent group
        .each(function (d,i) {
            console.log("hi", i); //i am getting index here.
        })
        .transition()
        .delay((1000*1+=1)) //how to delay?
        .duration(500)
        .select('.subAppPath') //first child
        .style('opacity', 1);

    d3.selectAll('.subAppGroup')
        .transition()
        .delay((1000*1+=i)) //both not working
        .duration(500)
        .select('.subAppGroupDetail') //second child

        .style('opacity', 1);

}

fadeHandler();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the logic inside a function.
i will be the index of the item in the array. In the example below element 0 will delay 0ms, element 1 100ms, and so on.

```
...
.delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 100; // Or whatever you want the delay to be.
})
...
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay

Edit: To answer your comment below, try this. I think this will work but it's hard to say without knowing what your data looks like.

```
var fadeHandler = function () {
    d3.selectAll('.subAppGroup .subAppPath, .subAppGroup .subAppGroupDetail')
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * 100;
        })
        .duration(500)
        .style('opacity', 1);
}

fadeHandler();
```

Comment: Is i require to do both children separately. can't i select both and add same delay and animate?

Comment: But i want the delay between, '.subAppPath' and '.subAppGroupDetail' how to add that? once the 'subAppPath' complete i need to start with 'subAppGroupDetail' of it's sibling.

Comment: I don't know. I can't answer it without knowing what your data looks like and what you have provided doesn't make it clear. I answered the question you posted so just post a second question and maybe someone else can help you